# When to Use [Super init] iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the use of `[super init]` in Objective-C default methods and what are the condition in which we can use it in our custom methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it short:

A. Every class has one (typically) or more primary (designated) initializers. Before you do your own initialization you have to execute one of the super's primary initializers. For example, in `NSObject` `-init` is the primary initializer. If you have a subclass of `NSObject` you have to execute `init` (`NSObject`) before you do your own initialization:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
…
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)init // My primary initializer
{
   // Before I do my own -init, if have to execute super's -init
   self = [super init];
   …
}
@end
```

This holds, if your subclass has a new primary initializer:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
…
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)initMyClassWith… // My primary initializer, that's different from NSObject's
{
   // Before I do my own -initMyClass, if have to execute super's -init
   self = [super init]; 
   // As long, as -init is not overridden, self-init would work by acdident, 
   // but you have to override on a PI change, see below!
   …
}
@end
```

You do *not* send `init` to `super` (more general: execute the PI of super), when you have a convenient initializer. In this case you send the message to self:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
…
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)initConvenient // My secondary initializer
{
   self = [self initMyClass]; // primary
   …
}
@end
```

Therefore on a PI change, you have to override the super's PI to make it execute the subclass' PI:

```
    @interface MyClass : NSObject
…
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (id)init // subclass' secondary
{
  self = [self initMyClass]; // Primary
   …
}
@end
```

Comment: "primary" is called "designated".

Comment: Depends of the age of the documentation: Earlier Apple used "designated" and "secondary". In our days Apple uses "designated" and "convenient". Before that I switch to "primary" and "secondary" to make the naming consistently. I bet, in the next OS release they have new names again. ;-)

Comment: Both Obj-C and Swift documentation is using designated and convenience (not convenient). Obj-C docs is using them for years, there are also macros and attributes for "designated".

Comment: I do not know what you mean with "for years", but definitely not "four years".

Comment: The macros seems to appear mid 2014 with Xcode 6. This is definitely not "for years", but less than a year (9 month).

Comment: The docs was using them when I started with Obj-C 5 ears ago :) The macro is only a simpler notation for LLVM attribute `__attribute__((objc_designated_initializer))` which is there at least 2 years.

Comment: 1. With the last edition of my book (2012) or so they used the old naming. 2. You talked about macros, not clang attributes. As far as I found on a quick look the clang attribute was added in Dec 2013 (less than 2 years) to the general version of clang. So it is pretty likely that they came to Xcode with Xcode 6, too.

Comment: Found that http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=196314 "[objc] Introduce attribute 'objc_designated_initializer'."

Comment: I have always seen the term "designated initializer" in Apple's docs, never anything else, since about 2007. (Starting on Mac)

Comment: @DuncanC Please read the whole discussion, esp. my first response. Thanks.

Comment: The correct term is "designated initializer". Using a made up expression for this well known concept is just confusing.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Please read the whole discussion, esp. my first response. Using "designated" and "convenience" (or "convenient") has the problem that there are convenience allocators, which has 1. nothing to do with convenience inits and additionally does not have a primary, designated, whatever allocator. So they have a name that seems to refer to inits, but does not.  BTW: I added that term.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad There is no such thing as a "convenience allocator". You seem to confuse the terms allocator and initializer. You should re-read the documentation: ["Concepts in Objective-C Programming"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW1). This paper introduces all the terms and concepts.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Really not? https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=convenience+allocator&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=SC8IVbPVHOGI8Qf6p4HQCg

Comment: No, [actually really no.](https://www.google.de/search?rls=en&q=site:developer.apple.com+%22convenience+allocator%22)

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Oh, I did not know that you do not know the changes following the introduction of ARC. Let me know, if you want further explanations. I thought that this is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You use `[super init]` in all subclasses you implement that have also an -init, -initWith... method.

It' to ensure that the parent class code is executed before yours.

[Details explanations](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/classes)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `super init` when you are overriding an initializer from your super class. For example if you are subclassing `UIViewController`, you call `[super init]` and then you add your custom initialization code.

Comment: To be more precise: No, in many cases you do not have to send a message to `super`, sometimes it breaks things. But is is true for `-init…`.

Comment: Actually he's asking about initializers. And there you  have to call super init.

Comment: I changed my comment. But it is still not true, because you have execute super's init only in a primary initializer. If it is a secondary initializer (convenient initializer) you have to execute the primary initializer of `self`.

Comment: Additionally you have to send super-init if you have a new primary initializer.